# Orphaned roleassignments - just a case of bad luck?

Tags: orphan

I notice on SharePointExchange there has been a lot of discussion in relation to various orphaned SP objects but nothing about Content Database role assignments orphans. In our farm virtually every content DB has numerous role assigment orphans (almost 1400 in one particular db).

The puzzling thing is when we ran some SQL reports on our content DBs it turns out 50% of these orphans relate to system lists such as the RoutingRules list. Given we don't routinely go in and change permissions in these lists I'm wondering what could possibly cause the orphans.

Could it be that performing routine tasks such as creating new content organizer rules generates these orphans as a normal by-product?

Microsoft says:

> Over time, the content database can accumulate objects that are corrupted. An object that should have a parent object might be orphaned; an object that should have a child object might not have one. These things can happen due to a variety of misfortunes: power failures, lost connectivity, application timeouts, software faults, or just plain bad luck."

Truthfully, bad luck, are they serious?

My other question relates to running the repair for these orphans. My impression, from doing a lot of reading,  is that repairing these suckers is fairly routine but are there any risks in running a repair that I should be aware of?